# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int^{1}_{0}{\frac{e^x}{1+x^n}\mbox{d}x \mbox{?}}$

Tags: integration, limits

How can I calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int^{1}_{0}{\frac{e^x}{1+x^n}\mbox{d}x \mbox{?}}$$

Is all right if I say that the initial limit is equivalent with $$\int^{1}_{0}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{e^x}{1+x^n}}\mbox{d}x}=\int^{1}_{0}{e^x}\mbox{d}x=e-1\mbox{?}$$

I have to prove that quantity under integral is bounded?

thanks :)

Comment: $[0,1]$ is compact, $\frac{e^x}{1+x^n}$ is elementary and defined there.

Comment: Whether it's all right depends on what theorems you have at your disposal. And what integral it is also plays a role for what limit operations are allowed. Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: it's about Riemann integration.

Comment: See either [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability) (for Riemann integral) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) for Lebesgue's one.
Second theorem is stronger and easier to apply, but requires (at least in an underlying fashion) a more complex definition of the integral.

For Riemann integral, you'll mainly have to prove uniform convergence of your sequence of functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the convergence is not uniform on the entire interval $[0,\, 1]$. So split the interval into $[0,\,1-\delta]$ and $[1-\delta,\,1]$. Convergence is uniform on the first one, you have an estimate of $e - e^{1-\delta}$ on the second. Combine to reach your goal.

Comment: @DanielFischer: oh, indeed — my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use any theorems regarding swapping integration with limits you can do it elementarily. Observe $e-1=\int_0^1 e^xdx$. So you need to prove that
$$
\int_0^1 (e^x/(1+x^n)-e^x)dx =-\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}e^xdx
$$
tends to zero. The absolute value of this is smaller than $e\int_0^1 x^ndx=e/(n+1)$.